# MVC 3/4 Razor Help needed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to create Menu for the master page. I've faced with following problem

```
<ul class="main_menu">

    @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes) 
    {
        int i = 1;
        <li class="**HOW TO ADD HERE A CLASS like level+i.ToString()?????**">@Html.DisplayFor(m => node) | 
            @if (node.Children.Any()) {
                <ul class="menuchild" style="display: none;">
                    <li>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => node.Children)
                    </li>
                </ul>
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

I need to create levels for the menu for Javascript , say level1 , level2 , level3 , how to combine strings inside Razor.

Thanks.

Comment: you are not incrementing your variable i, like i++ inside your foreach loop. Also to add an incremental class do something like <li class=@("level" +  i.toString())/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose with @()

```
<li class="@("level" + i.ToString() )">
```

or

```
<li class="@string.Format("level{0}", i)">
```